# Computed properties and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm a little confused on how computed properties work with Vuex. I'm using  a computed getter:

```
var selectDisplayValues = computed({
    get() {
        return store.getters['expense/getSelectDisplayValues'];
    }
});
```

When the store data changes the computed prop also changes. So far so clear.
When now assigning a new value to the computed property - the value inside the store also changes. Not just the local value of the property. Why is that so? Won't I need a setter inside the computed prop to do so?

EDIT:
I'm assigning the new values like this.

```
selectDisplayValues.value[`inputData[${props.index}][${props.attribute}]`] = {placeholder_value: "Bitte wählen...", value: "", reassigned: false};
```

Also I'm using a v-model on a select dropdown for changing them according to the options value.

Comment: "When now assigning a new value to the computed property" - how exactly do you do that? Please, post all relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new value wasn't assigned but existing value was mutated.

Getter-only computed ref has read-only `value` property that contains unmodified value.

If the intention is to make ref value deeply read-only, this needs to be explicitly done:

```
const selectDisplayValues = readonly(toRef(store.getters, 'expense/getSelectDisplayValues'))
```

Comment: So your point is, when using the `.value` of the computed property, it's no longer read only, but also writable (even inside the store)?

Comment: Properties of an object that computed function returns weren't read-only, they won't be read-only. It's selectDisplayValues.value that is read-only, you won't be able to reassign it

Comment: Okay, so I won't need a computed setter to change or add values to an object inside the store at all, if i get it correctly?

Comment: You may need to, depending on how you use it. It's a bad practice to modify Vuex state explicitly, this should always be done with commit or dispatch, and that's where `set` comes into play

Comment: Yea, I know it normally should be done with a mutation, in strict mode it won't work like that. But in that special case a mutation would be quite unhandy to handle. So thanks for your help and information. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would personaly recommand using `mapGetters` from vuex  : [the mapgetters helper](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper)

I works like this :

You decalre a getter un your vuex store :

```js
const store = createStore({
  state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    doneTodos (state) {
      return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
    }
  }
})
```

And in your vue component :

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      doneCount: 'doneTodosCount'
   })
  }
}
```

You can then access value from your getter with `this.doneCount`

If the store change the computed value wil automatically change

Comment: mapGetters is for options API, while the question uses composition API. There are still no first-party Vuex helpers for composition.